# Does Flink support map side aggregations? (batch)

Tags: apache-flink

Spark has the concept of [map-side combine](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ShuffledRDD.scala#L52) so that you're able to perform partial aggregations so that you reduce (pun unintended) shuffling.

Is there something equivalent in Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Flink provides multiple interfaces to define (map-side) combiners.

- `GroupCombineFunction<IN, OUT>` combines a subset of a group of input type `IN` into one or more combined values of type `OUT`
- `CombineFunction<IN, OUT>` combines a subset of a group of input type `IN` into a single value of type `OUT`
- `ReduceFunction<T>` combines pairs of type `T` into a single value of type `T`. This function is automatically used for combining (pre-aggregation) and reducing (full aggregation).